# Contraction with a vector field and pullback bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, hochschild-cohomology

While trying to understand the proof of "smooth" version of Kostant-Hochschild-Rosenberg theorem (which is due to Connes for compact smooth manifolds) I found the following argumentation: one is interested in finding a projective resolution for $C^{\infty}(M)$ over $C^{\infty}(M \times M)$ of the form
$...P_k \stackrel{i_X}{\longrightarrow} P_{k-1} \stackrel{i_X}{\longrightarrow} ... \stackrel{i_X}{\longrightarrow} P_1 \stackrel{i_X}{\longrightarrow} P_0=C^{\infty}(M \times M) \stackrel{\Delta^*}{\longrightarrow} C^{\infty}(M) \to 0$.
The modules $P_k$ are costructed as follows: take $k$-th exterior power of (complexified) cotangent bundle, then consider its pullback via $pr_2: M \times M \to M, (x,y) \mapsto y$ and denote this by $E_k$. Then $P_k$ is defined as $\Gamma^{\infty}(M \times M,E_k)$ (the module of smooth sections of $E_k$). Further, $\Delta^*f(x)=f(x,x)$ (in other words $\Delta^*(f)=f \circ \Delta$). However I don't really see how to interpret $i_X$:
-I'm familiar with the usual contraction with a vector field defined via $(i_X\omega )(X_1,...,X_n)=\omega(X,X_1,...,X_n)$ where $\omega$ is a $n+1$ form
-according to text on which I'm based, I concluded that $X$ should take a point $(x,y) \in M \times M$ and send it to the tangent space $T_y(M)$
-Moreover they write the following: in order for the above sequence to be exact at $P_0$ it is sufficient and necessary that $X_{(x,x)}=0$ and $X_{(x,y)} \neq 0$
Having all this information my question is the following:

> How precisely is the map $i_X$ defined in this context?

Comment: It seems like $X$ is a relative vector field along the projection $pr_2$, wich is presicely an object which associates to every $(x,y)$ a tangent vector at $y$ in $M$. Now elements in $P_k$ can also be thought of as relative differential forms, so to every $(x,y)$ you atach a k-covector at $y$, and so insertion is defined, as you say, in the usual way producing a realitve k-1 form